# Capturing DNS traffic and save to a file every hour with tcpdump

Tags: linux, bash, cron, debian, tcpdump

I want to capture my DNS A record traffic and save it to a file every hour. What bash script and cron process should I use for this?

Comment: What is a "DNS A record traffic"?  You want to capture the result of `nslookup` or you are on the DNS server and you want to record the queries to your server (log files), or all the traffic to a server (tcpdump), ...?

Comment: I want to capture all the traffic to my DNS server. But in tcpdump i can see AAAA and PTR records as well. I don't want to capture them.

Comment: You will have to filter the server logs, or the tcpdump results (capture configuration or process the capture to keep only what you need).